# How to start a "new Game.class" when the player lost?

Tags: java, android

I know my title is quite confusing but have no idea how I can ask this question in the most understandable. Hope you understand.

In my game there are 2 classes

1. "**mainActivity**" the game view.
2. "**Game**" extends the SurfaceView and implements Runnable (the game loop).

First screen displays with the button "Start New Game" and once you click on the button setContentView replaces its display view game.class.

So far everything is working properly. Now, suppose that the player lost I want to return to the main screen and as soon as he clicks the "Start New Game" game starts from beginning.

Currently clicking the back button "restart the game from the 0"

Here are my classes:

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

    DialogPause pauseDialog;
    public  MyPreferences pref;
    private TextView txCoins;
    public  Game game;
    public static Music music;
    ViewAnimator viewAnimator;


    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        pref = new MyPreferences(this);
        music = new Music(this);
        pauseDialog = new DialogPause(this);

        setContentView(R.layout.menu);

        view();
    }

    public void view(){
        txCoins = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txCoins);
        txCoins.setText("Coins "+pref.getInt("coins"));
    }

    public  void newGame(){
        if(game != null){
            game.destroyed();
        }
        game = new Game(this);
        game.start();
        game.setOnTouchListener(this);
        setContentView(game);
    }

    public void click(View v){
            newGame();
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        music.StopBackgroundMusic();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        newGame();
    }
```

**Game loop class:**

```
public class Game extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{

    public static  MyPreferences pref;
    public static Levels level;
    public static int SCREEN_W;
    public static int SCREEN_H;
    public static  boolean running;
    public static  boolean pause = false;
    private  Thread thread = null;
    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    private Canvas canvas;
    private Paint p = new Paint();
    public static Handler handler = new Handler();
    public static Resources res;
    public  Timer timer;

    public Game(Context context) {
        super(context);
        res = getResources();
        holder = getHolder();
        level = new Levels();
        timer = new Timer();
        pref = new MyPreferences(context);
        System.out.println("Create Game instance");
    }

    public void run() {
        init();

        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double delta = 0;
        double ns = 1000000000.0 / 30.0;
        System.out.println("Run method" + running);
        //Start looping...
        while (running) {
            //If it's not pause 

            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta+=(now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;

            if(!holder.getSurface().isValid()){continue;}

            canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            SCREEN_W = canvas.getWidth();
            SCREEN_H= canvas.getHeight();


            while (delta >-1) {
                if(!pause)tick();
                    delta--;
            }

            level.level1();
            render(canvas); 
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

            if(ControlPanel.PLAYER_POWER <=0){
                System.out.println("Loose!");
                ControlPanel.PLAYER_POWER  = 100;
                stop();
                start();
            }
        }
    }

    private void render(Canvas c) {
        handler.render(c);
        textOnScreen(c);
    }

    public void tick(){
        handler.tick();
    }

    public void init(){
        ControlPanel.COINS = pref.getInt("coins");
        MainActivity.music.backgroundMusic();
        handler.addSpaceShip(new Player(500, 500, 10, 10, handler, Sprite.getSprite(0)));

//      handler.addKing(new King(Game.SCREEN_W / 2, 100,
//              40, 40, handler, Sprite.getSprite(18), 0));
    }

    public  void start() {
        //If the tread are new one
        if(thread==null){
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();     
        timer.start();
        }
        //if it not running
        if(!running)    {
            pause = false;
            running =true;
        }
    }


    public  void stop() {
        pause = true;
        running = false;
        timer.stop();
        pref.putInt("coins", ControlPanel.COINS);
    }


    public void pause() {
        pause = true;
    }

    public  void destroyed() {
        System.out.println("Stop");
        running = false;
        this.stop();
    }

    public void textOnScreen(Canvas c){
        p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        p.setTextSize(50);
        c.drawText("POWER = " + ControlPanel.PLAYER_POWER, SCREEN_W / 2 ,50 , p);
        c.drawText("Time = " + timer.timeFormat(), 100  ,50 , p);
        c.drawText("Coins = " + ControlPanel.COINS, 10 ,SCREEN_H - 10 , p);
        p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        c.drawText("Bullets = " +ControlPanel.BULLET, SCREEN_W - 390,SCREEN_H - 10 , p);
        p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        c.drawText(ControlPanel.Distance + " km ", SCREEN_W  /2  - 200,SCREEN_H - 10 , p);
    }

}
```

Please help!! I've been a week and a half and can not solve it :((

Comment: Can you include your layout as well? Also, is there any reason why you don't have two activities instead of one? So, your MainActivity would include the start screen, while the GameActivity would include the actual game? Finally, `System.out.println("Loose!");` should be `System.out.println("Lost!");` :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you want to return to your first menu when it reaches `System.out.println("Loose!");` because you said it already works quite well now. I donnot have time to read all the code but if it is what you want then you can try this solution. I added handler variable in each class to restart the program.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

DialogPause pauseDialog;
public  MyPreferences pref;
private TextView txCoins;
public  Game game;
public static Music music;
ViewAnimator viewAnimator;
Handler uiHandler = new Handler(){
   @override
   public void handleMessage (Message msg){
         restart();
   }
}


@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    pref = new MyPreferences(this);
    music = new Music(this);
    pauseDialog = new DialogPause(this);

    setContentView(R.layout.menu);

    view();
}


private void restart(){
     setContentView(R.layout.menu);
     view();
}

public void view(){
    txCoins = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txCoins);
    txCoins.setText("Coins "+pref.getInt("coins"));
}

public  void newGame(){
    if(game != null){
        game.destroyed();
    }
    game = new Game(this, handler);
    game.start();
    game.setOnTouchListener(this);
    setContentView(game);
}

public void click(View v){
        newGame();
}

protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    music.StopBackgroundMusic();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //newGame(); //comment out this
}
```

And Game class:

```
public class Game extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{

private Handler handler;
public static  MyPreferences pref;
public static Levels level;
public static int SCREEN_W;
public static int SCREEN_H;
public static  boolean running;
public static  boolean pause = false;
private  Thread thread = null;
private SurfaceHolder holder;
private Canvas canvas;
private Paint p = new Paint();
public static Handler handler = new Handler();
public static Resources res;
public  Timer timer;

public Game(Context context, Handler handler) {
    super(context);
    this.handler = handler;
    res = getResources();
    holder = getHolder();
    level = new Levels();
    timer = new Timer();
    pref = new MyPreferences(context);
    System.out.println("Create Game instance");
}

public void run() {
    init();

    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double delta = 0;
    double ns = 1000000000.0 / 30.0;
    System.out.println("Run method" + running);
    //Start looping...
    while (running) {
        //If it's not pause 

        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta+=(now - lastTime) / ns;
        lastTime = now;

        if(!holder.getSurface().isValid()){continue;}

        canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
        SCREEN_W = canvas.getWidth();
        SCREEN_H= canvas.getHeight();


        while (delta >-1) {
            if(!pause)tick();
                delta--;
        }

        level.level1();
        render(canvas); 
        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

        if(ControlPanel.PLAYER_POWER <=0){
            System.out.println("Loose!");

            ControlPanel.PLAYER_POWER  = 100;
            stop();
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);//restart the game menu as u want
            //start();//Comment out this
        }
    }
}

private void render(Canvas c) {
    handler.render(c);
    textOnScreen(c);
}

public void tick(){
    handler.tick();
}

public void init(){
    ControlPanel.COINS = pref.getInt("coins");
    MainActivity.music.backgroundMusic();
    handler.addSpaceShip(new Player(500, 500, 10, 10, handler, Sprite.getSprite(0)));

//      handler.addKing(new King(Game.SCREEN_W / 2, 100,
//              40, 40, handler, Sprite.getSprite(18), 0));
}

public  void start() {
    //If the tread are new one
    if(thread==null){
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();     
    timer.start();
    }
    //if it not running
    if(!running)    {
        pause = false;
        running =true;
    }
}


public  void stop() {
    pause = true;
    running = false;
    timer.stop();
    pref.putInt("coins", ControlPanel.COINS);
}


public void pause() {
    pause = true;
}

public  void destroyed() {
    System.out.println("Stop");
    running = false;
    this.stop();
}

public void textOnScreen(Canvas c){
    p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    p.setTextSize(50);
    c.drawText("POWER = " + ControlPanel.PLAYER_POWER, SCREEN_W / 2 ,50 , p);
    c.drawText("Time = " + timer.timeFormat(), 100  ,50 , p);
    c.drawText("Coins = " + ControlPanel.COINS, 10 ,SCREEN_H - 10 , p);
    p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    c.drawText("Bullets = " +ControlPanel.BULLET, SCREEN_W - 390,SCREEN_H - 10 , p);
    p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    c.drawText(ControlPanel.Distance + " km ", SCREEN_W  /2  - 200,SCREEN_H - 10 , p);
}

}
```